# Automatically extract road points from a point cloud

Tags: geospatial

My goal is to extract points belonging to a road from a point cloud that has geospatial annotations. I wonder if there exists some openly accessible database/tool with exact coordinates of a road's edges?

Comment: openstreetmap.org would be the place to start, unless you're worried about road widths as well? Or is that the issue?